# Why is it not possible to resize ExFAT partitions?

Tags: partitioning, exfat

I wonder why no partition editor allows you to shrink or enlarge exFAT partitions without having to actually delete it and make it again.

Comment: The title and the description contradict each other. The title asks why it is NOT possible to resize exfat, and the description asks why it IS possible

Comment: My guess is "nobody has written a tool for it yet".